# Hibernate: How to Join Columns from 2 entities which haves composite primary keys

Tags: java, database, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to have a join from Table A and Table B.
I need a list of Table B elements by a join from the foreign key of Table B and one of the primary keys of Table A.

Table A:

a1 pk

b1 pk

c1 pk

d1

e1

---

Table B

f1 pk

g1 pk and fk of b1 column in Table A

h1 pk

i1

l1

---

I have 4 entity class: A, APK, B, BPK

Class A:

```
@EmbeddedId

private APK id;

@Column(name = "d1")

private String d1;

@Column(name = "e1")

private String e1;
```

---

Class APK:

```
@Column(name = "a1")

private String a1;

@Column(name = "b1")

private String b1;

@Column(name = "c1")
private String c1;
```

---

Class B:

```
@EmbeddedId

private BPK id;

@Column(name = "i1")

private String i1;

@Column(name = "l1")

private String l1;
```

---

Class BPK:

```
@Column(name = "f1")

private String f1;

@Column(name = "g1")

private String g1;

@Column(name = "h1")

private String h1;
```

---

How can I relate column g1 of table B to column b1 of table A for have a list of B elements in the A Entity?
It's a @OneToMany relationship.

Thanks